# Algorithm for assembling nodes in a 3D layer/mesh

Tags: algorithm, 3d, mesh

This question might be a bit abstract, it's not about any library or language.

Imagine there's a layer of nodes in 3D space, dispersed randomly in the vicinity of an imaginary surface.

What's the algorithm to assemble those nodes into a mesh or a flexible layer, so that if we would connect those nodes by elastic feedback links and then pull one node, then the whole layer begins to flex and move, rather than decompose?

The simplest way is the follows: Just connect each node to its 6-10 nearest nodes. If node placement is regular this is going to work, but if for some reason there's a hole in nodes' distribution, chances that edge nodes will only be connected to nearest nodes from one side. When you pull layer like this, holes begin to grow as demonstrated on the screenshot of two distinct spherical layers, both with holes in them:

[image: Two layers of nodes with holes in them]

So: Is there an algorithm to select N nodes to connect for a given node, in 3D space, that will prevent the formation of holes? If holes have already formed, what's the algorithm to make them over, provided that connections between nodes pull elastically?

Note that layers has "up and down" and then "left, right, forward, backward" directions in 3D space.
It's very important that every cell has at least one left, right, forward and backward connection. However, up direction and down direction may as well be empty.
We may assume hexagon symmetry instead of cubic, with same idea.

I think that ideal set of connected cells should be that sum of their distance vectors from a given cell are as close to zero as possible. However I can't think of even a polynominal way to select an M subset of N neighbours, so that their vectors' sum is as close to zero as possible. Seems like an NP task if done bluntly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought based on my understanding of your question: cut the 3D space into layers that are, say x units high, and categorize the nodes into these layers. Imagine this layer flat on a surface. Lets say we start from the bottom, for each of all the nodes that has no nodes under it within a considerable range:

Start from this node. Look for some nodes around it. However, when calculating the distance between the target and our node, the closer it is to the line parallel to the y-axis passing through the starting node, the more we compensate the distance (use a function like gaussian distribution or such), the further away it's to the line we penalise it by multiplying a factor larger than one. This way the connection would be "directional" but allows some degree of deviation depending on how you set your constants in the function. Connect our current node with the node that has the lowest "weighted" distance. Repeat this process for the new node, until the node has no nodes that's above it within the considerable range.

Now switch the axes, in this case start from the left, and do the same thing. This, depending on how you write your 'weighting' function, may tolerate different degrees of holes. Once you're done with both the x-axis and the y-axis you'll have something like a distorted grid. There probably will be some nodes that are unconnected because they are not being friendly with everyone else, but you can connect them to the nearest 4~6 nodes or do something like that.

If your nodes are dispersed in a spherical way in the 3d space you can probably do this procedure in all 3 axis: x, y and z.

Comment: Isn't it just "connect the dispersed points on a surface covering any holes"? You just put nodes that are approximately on the same height to a surface, and process these nodes as a whole. Don't worry about other nodes that are not in the layer, it turns into a 2D problem.

Comment: Now it becomes hugely anisotropic: if a node lies on an axis it will be linked even if it's pretty far away, if it is located diagonally it will be ignored even if it's very near. We can make 3 hexagonal axes not 2 cubic, but the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: @alamar It depends on how you set your weighting function. Also, the whole point about filling the hole is that you have to connect across the hole, which is probably a pretty far distance.